# Null pointer exception serenity behave root package

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run a simple bdd test using behave and serenity but i am getting a initialization error. It seems as though there is a package class which is null but i cannot figure out which one or is there something wrong with way i am initialising my code.

I have been serenity bdd documentation online 
https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/jbehave.html

[directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX15l.png)
[new output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJud3.png)

Appreciate the help :)

Below is the stack trace and code.

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.RootPackage.forPackage(RootPackage.java:8)
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories.getRootPackage(SerenityStories.java:220)
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStories.stepsFactory(SerenityStories.java:88)
    at org.jbehave.core.ConfigurableEmbedder.configuredEmbedder(ConfigurableEmbedder.java:130)
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.runners.SerenityReportingRunner.<init>(SerenityReportingRunner.java:68)
    at net.serenitybdd.jbehave.runners.SerenityReportingRunner.<init>(SerenityReportingRunner.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:70)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.createRunner(ClassRequest.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.MemoizingRequest.getRunner(MemoizingRequest.java:19)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

test.class

```
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Managed;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Steps;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class test {
    @Managed()
    WebDriver webDriver;

 @Steps
    GoogleSteps googleSteps;


    @When("I open the page $value")
    public void itest(String value) {

        googleSteps.sendvalue(value);

    }


}
```

GooglePage.class

```
import net.serenitybdd.core.annotations.findby.By;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.DefaultUrl;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.pages.PageObject;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;


@DefaultUrl("http://www.google.com")
public class GooglePage extends PageObject {


 public void searchGoogle (String q) {
     find(By.name("q")).sendKeys(q, Keys.ENTER);


 }
}
```

GoogleSteps.class

```
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;

public class GoogleSteps {

    GooglePage googlePage;


    @Step
    public void open_page() {

        googlePage.open();
    }

    @Step
    public void sendvalue (String value) {

        googlePage.searchGoogle(value);
    }
}
```

GoogleRunner.class

```
import net.serenitybdd.jbehave.SerenityStory;


public class GoogleRunner extends SerenityStory {

}
```

serenity.properties file

```
webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver = /Users/aneesaiqbal/Downloads/chromedriver-2.exe
```

login.story

```
Narrative:
Testing google
Scenario: lets google

When I open the page hello
```

Comment: I think **GoogleSteps** should **extends ScenarioSteps** so make it  **public class GoogleSteps extends ScenarioSteps** . try it and let me know.

Comment: What is the version of [serenity-jbehave](https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-jbehave) you use?

Comment: @Muzzamil i made this change and i am still presented with the same error.

Comment: @Boris I am using version 1.46.0

Comment: How do you run the tests and what is the project [directory tree](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431251/how-to-print-the-directory-tree-in-terminal)?

Comment: @Boris Thanks for your reply. I have attached a screenshot of my directory tree. I am no longer presented with the error i had before because i used the same package name in my test that is in my main. However when i run my test class, it passes  and it seem serenity is running but my classes are not being detected. I have added a screen shot of the output in my question. I think its the way i have structured my directories.

Comment: When trying to compile your project, I'm getting a compilation error. Look at `GoogleSteps`, it refers `GooglePage`, but according to the directory tree it resides in a different directory - Pages. Please double check and update the source code with package statements.